# Use the Jsoup API : [parse(File in, String charsetName, String baseUri)]

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, uri

I am using jsoup to parse some HTML but I don't know why I am not getting the results I expect.

Q1: I want the output URL to be `http://example.com/input/img.jpg`, but it outputs `http://example.com/img.jpg`.

Q2: The resulting HTML is `<img src="/img.jpg">`, but I want it to be `<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">`.

## Input HTML file

```
<!-- HTML file -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JsoupInputTest</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv">test parsing input file by jsoup</div>
        <img src="/img.jpg">
        <a href="/a.jpg">s1 test</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Code

```
public static void inputTest() throws IOException{

    String fileName = "../inputTest.html";
    File in = new File(fileName);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/input/");

    System.out.println(doc.select("img").first().absUrl("src"));
    System.out.println(doc.select("a[href]").first().absUrl("href"));

    System.out.println("====================================");

    System.out.println(doc.html());
}
```

## Output

```
http://example.com/img.jpg
http://example.com/a.jpg
====================================`enter code here`
<!-- HTML file --><!doctype html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>JsoupInputTest</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div id="mydiv">
   test parsing input file by jsoup
  </div> 
  <img src="/img.jpg"> 
  <a href="/a.jpg">s1 test</a>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Nathan Van Dyken thank you for that your edited my question

Answer (score 1):

the answer from Jsoup Author Jhy:[#908](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/908)

> Q1: both of those are absolute URLs with implicit domains -- the URL
>   starts with a single slash. So only the hostname from the base HREF
>   (the third argument to Jsoup.parse) is used. The output is correct.
>
> See
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs
>   for some more details on how URLs are made absolute.
>
> Q2: calling absUrl() doesn't change the value in the DOM; it's
>   calculating the absolute URL, not updating it.